# Getting both or one Checkbox value in for each loop

Tags: php, checkbox, foreach

I have a form that the user can submit either 1 or 2 checked boxes. It must be at least 1. The checkbox setup looks like so:

```
    <input name="request['+fields+'][Type of Folder:]" 
id="cbpathCDB'+fields+'" type="checkbox" 
value="Content Database" class="cbShowPath required" data-id="'+fields+'"/>

    <input name="request['+fields+'][Type of Folder:]" 
id="cbpathEFS'+fields+'" type="checkbox" 
value="File System" class="efsShowPath required" data-id="'+fields+'"/>
```

There is other inputs that are also being submitted, so I am using this for each:

```
$a=$_REQUEST['request'];        

        foreach ($a as $name) {         
            foreach ($name as $key => $desc) {
                if ($desc !== '') {
                    $note.= $key;
                    $note.= $desc;
                }
            }
        }
```

This gets all the data fine if the user checks ONE checkbox, but if the user checks both checkboxes, only the value of the FIRST checkbox is shown.

What do I need to do here in order to get both values?

Do I need a 3rd foreach in here to get name="request[][][]"?

EDIT: some updates here...

If I use his foreach:

```
foreach ($a as $name) {         
            foreach ($name as $key => $desc) {
                foreach ($desc as $d){
                        $note.= $key;
                        $note.= $d; 
                }
                if ($desc !== '') {
                        $note.= $key;
                        $note.= $desc;
                }
            }
        }
```

I get these results echoed out: 
**Type of Folder:Content DBType of Folder:File SystemType of Folder:Array**

If I use his foreach:

```
        foreach ($a as $name) {         
        foreach ($name as $key => $desc) {
            if ($desc !== '') {
                $note.= $key;
                $note.= $desc;
            }
        }
    }
```

I get these results echoed out: 
**Type of Folder:Array**

Comment: Those are some *terribly* ugly field names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of the form elements to

```
request['+fields+'][Type of Folder:][]
```

So for your code

```
<input name="request['+fields+'][Type of Folder:][]" id="cbpathCDB'+fields+'" type="checkbox" value="Content Database" class="cbShowPath required" data-id="'+fields+'"/>

<input name="request['+fields+'][Type of Folder:][]" id="cbpathEFS'+fields+'" type="checkbox" value="File System" class="efsShowPath required" data-id="'+fields+'"/>
```

This will make `$_REQUEST['request']["'+fields+'"]['Type of Folder:']` an array containing the value of each checked box.

You need to modify the part of your code working with `$desc` to include another loop.

```
foreach ($a as $name) {         
  foreach ($name as $key => $desc) {
    switch (gettype($desc)) {
      case 'array':
        foreach ($desc as $i => $item) {
          $note .= "{$key}[{$i}]";
          $note .= $item;
        }
        break;
      case 'string':
      default:
        if ($desc !== '') {
          $note.= $key;
          $note.= $desc;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ZOIX! that was fast man. I did try that a few mins ago, I get the result as ARRAY. How come the names don't come through only ARRAY?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The name for both checkboxes in your question are the same, so appending `[]` to the field name of each will allow both to be mapped to the `['request']["'+fields+'"]['Type of Folder:']`. You access each with the index of the array the checkbox correcsponds to. `$_REQUEST['request']["'+fields+'"]['Type of Folder:'][0]`,  `$_REQUEST['request']["'+fields+'"]['Type of Folder:'][1]`, etc...

Comment: Yes, right. That makes sense to me, thanks. What I get from the foreach, echoed out, is Array, which is right in a way, but I am not sure why I am not getting the results echoed out ---> Type of Folder: Content DB, Type of Folder: File System... I am just getting the words Array. Where Type of Folder is found in the name=[][][] and value = Conent DB or File System

Comment: Thanks for the help @Deefour. I am able to get the value of each checkbox adding a third foreach: foreach ($a as $name) {   
   foreach ($name as $key => $desc) {
    foreach ($desc as $d){
     if ($desc !== '') {
           $note.= $key;
      $note.= $d;
        }
    }
   }
  }, but then I don't get any of the other results... Can I not get the results of multiple inputs of 2 dimensional arrays and also pull the results from one that is 3 dimensional as this checkbox idea is?

Comment: Because your `$_REQUEST` object is of mixed type, you need to look at the type of each input coming in. You can't just blindly loop through  every input treating them all as arrays or strings; you need to handle each type of input independently *(hence the switch statement in my edit above)*.

Comment: ah, I didn't see that before I posted the 3rd comment. Yes, that works. Genius! thanks man!

Comment: The gettype() function is great! I haven't used that before. Thanks again.